# Obtener los datos de una propiedad en una clase por nombre

Tags: javascript, typescript

Se tiene la siguiente interfaz

```
export interface Contribuyente {
    Campo1: number;
    Campo2: string;
    Campo3: number;
    Campo4: number;
}
```

Y despues se genera la siguiente interfaz

```
export interface AppState {
    Contribuyentes: Contribuyente[];
}
```

Y con esto se genera una "clase"

```
export const state: AppState = {
    Columnas: [],
    Contribuyentes: [
        { Campo1: 1, Campo2: 'N', Campo3: 1, Campo4: 75, },
        ......
    ]
}
```

Y ahora lo que quiero hacer, es en un metodo, obtener los datos contenidos por ejemplo en Campo1, pero solo recibiendo como parametro en el mismo, el nombre del Campo1.

La solucion trivial es dado el nombre del campo, hacer un gran switch y devolver el campo que corresponde:

```
public obtenercampo(campo: string): string {
    switch (campo) {
        case 'Campo1':
            valor = clase.Campo1;
            break;
        ....
    }
    .....
}
```

Pero si la interfaz Contribuyente tuviera 30 campos, este modelo no es bonito.

Hay alguna otra forma de acceder a esas propiedades, sabiendo el nombre del campo que quiero obtener?

Comment: Recién lo entiendo, ¿acaso [`hasOwnProperty('campo')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/hasOwnProperty) no es lo que buscas?

Comment: @MauricioContreras decime que no se entendio y lo arreglo.. viene por ahi, pero eso me dice si la propiedad esta.. yo quiero el valor de esa propiedad...

Comment: Lo sé, por lo tanto no necesitas tanto misterio, si la propiedad está te devuelve el valor (eso lo programas tu) y si no está no te devuelve nada (o te devuelve lo que tu quieras). Me explico?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes usar javascript bracket notation.
   Basicamente accedes a las propiedades de un objeto, con el nombre entre llaves.

```
   obj['property_name'];
```

Un Ejemplo del uso:

```
var user = { "name":"no named", "qty":24};
console.log(user['name']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Si mal no entiendo, tienes una clase y deseas generar un método mediante el cual al pasar como argumento el nombre de un campo, te devuelva el valor de dicho campo. Por favor corrígeme si lo que deseas lo entiendo mal.

La definición de tu método podría ir así:

```
public obtenerCampo(campo: string): any {
    return clase.hasOwnProperty(campo) ? clase[campo] : 'aqui devuelves lo que haga falta en caso de necesitarlo';
}
```

Lo que devuelvas con dicha función cuando el campo no exista lo varías de acuerdo a tus requerimientos. Si te fijas, he puesto que el valor devuelto por tu método sea de tipo `any`, ya que los atributos (propiedades) de tu clase son de diferente tipo.

**Edición**

Como indica @PabloLozano, la sentencia `return clase[campo]` devuelve `undefined` en caso que la propiedad `campo` no exista en la clase. Dado que no sé cual es el requerimiento, pongo una estructura de decisión para que se devuelva algún valor distinto de `undefined` si fuese necesario.

Comment: la sentencia `return clase[campo];` ya devuelve `undefined` si no existe la propiedad

Comment: XD, claro, costumbre de escribir el código un poco más legible, por eso aclaro eso de que varíe el `return` de acuerdo a lo que necesite. Tal vez necesita un string vacío o un número, la idea es darle la opción.